# Change ok text of MUI datepicker dialog

Tags: material-ui, datepicker

How can i change datepicker dialog button text from OK to something like Apply. The MUI docs does not provide any props to help me change the title

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MUI's datepicker v5, the below works for me:

version from my package.json: `"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.16",`

```
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { AdapterLuxon } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon";
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

.....


<LocalizationProvider
  dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}
  localeText={{ cancelButtonLabel: 'Exit', clearButtonLabel: 'None', okButtonLabel: 'Save', todayButtonLabel: 'Set today' }}
>
    <DatePicker
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      inputFormat="dd MMM yyyy"
      disableMaskedInput
      value={DateTime.local()}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        console.log(params);
        return <TextField {...params} onClick={(e) => setOpen(true)} />;
      }}
      
      componentsProps={{
        actionBar: {
          actions: ["cancel", "clear", "accept", "today"],
        }
      }}

    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

- You can specify which buttons are displayed on the datepicker's calendar dialog by specifying the `componentsProps` for `datepicker`. The sequence of the buttons displayed follows the sequence in the array passed to `componentsProps->actionBar->actions`. In this case, the order of buttons will be:  cancel, clear, accept, today.
- You can change the label on the buttons by passing in `localeText` to the LocalizationProvider:
  `<LocalizationProvider localeText={{ cancelButtonLabel: 'Exit', clearButtonLabel: 'None', okButtonLabel: 'Save', todayButtonLabel: 'Set today' }}>`
- So you will see this buttons in the calendar dialog: `Exit, None, Save, Set today`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass `okLabel` prop to your datepicker component.

```
<DatePicker
  okLabel={"Apply"}
  {...props}
/>
```

Comment: Does not work on V5

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: I found another way, i used css after to replace text